# Help Me Identify This Capacitor

Tags: capacitor, identification, mlcc

This multi-layer ceramic capacitor indicated in the picture is missing. It's next to an internal memory chip for the Nintendo Switch LITE. I need to replace it but I don't know its specs. Could you help me figure it out? I have a very basic multimeter, how can I identify it?[image]

Comment: Pretty much impossible. But I would be tempted to just measure the remaining cap and use another one of the same value.

Comment: OK so to do that, do I need to desolder it from the board or is it OK to just unplug the battery in order to get an accurate reading? Also, I'm a newbie in Electronics. With that said, considering this board is connected to a battery, should I measure it using the Voltage option (DC)? After reading the remaining cap, how should that help me understand the EXACT capacitor to purchase? I appreciate your help.

Comment: Most likely you will need to remove it. Because there are probably a lot of capacitors in parallel with it elsewhere which would throw off the measurement. Once you have a value for the cap, just buy a similar value cap the same physical size. Voltage rating should be double the voltage on the cap or more (you should be able to measure the voltage even though the cap is not there...). Depending on the value and size, use a COG capacitor if it is available, and use X7R if COG is not available in that size/capacitance/voltage rating.

Comment: Take note that the board will probably work fine without the cap, and also you could just choose a value at random like 1uF. It is very unlikely that the cap is a critical component. Don't lose any sleep over this.

Comment: Addressing your previous comment, #1 I've got to desolder the cap from the board to get a reading. Is it in Ohms? #2 As for the physical size, that thing is way too small, it could be 1mm width and its height is even smaller, how does that translate in a criteria I could use to purchase another one? #3 after the cap is removed, measure the voltage of its pads, and purchase another cap which is capable of outputting double the rated voltage or more.. am I getting that right? Finally, should I avoid it if Mouser only has X5R options available?

Comment: @mkeith would it be possible to measure the capacitance with this multimeter? https://ibb.co/4fkttJG

Comment: I think you should just leave it off and see if the board works. It seems like you don't regularly work with this stuff, so why go through the headache? The cap is probably one of the following three sizes (using english sizes) 0402, 0603 or 0805. X5R is OK in my opinion. The cap doesn't put out a voltage. It tolerates a certain voltage. It is sort of like a strength rating in a cable or a pressure rating in a pipe. You want to make sure the voltage rating of the cap is higher than the voltage it will be exposed to. 2X safety factor is approximate.

Comment: that meter doesn't seem to be able to measure capacitors.

Comment: I would just leave it off, but I was told capacitors are used to make voltage potential in a circuit. Not sure what that means, but I guess they serve to keep things balanced and provide some extra juice when necessary. With that said, I'm afraid leaving that spot without a cap is going to lead to some more serious damage down the line. Been losing 11 days on this, asking away on different forums and then I found you. So I do apologize if I'm being a pain to deal with or if I've made too many questions.

Comment: @mkeith one final question, should I measure the VDC on the pad the capacitor is going to sit on or on the capacitor?

Comment: The pad its going to sit on.